# Bedeutung des Wortes kohärent

Tags: meaning

Ich frage mich gerade, ob es passend ist, im Kontext von kohärenten unterrichtlichen Inhalten von einem erkennbaren roten Faden der Inhalte zu reden. In anderen Worten also, dass alles in sich stimmig und logisch schlüssig ist, wie seht ihr das?

Man sagt ja auch ein Text ist kohärent und meint damit den roten Faden.

Comment: Willkommen auf dem German SE! Lies [diese](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/628/4788).

Comment: Warum nicht? Das ist doch ein gängiges Bild.

Comment: Ein Faden ist stringent. Kohärenz beschreibt eher ein Netz bei dem mehrere Punkte über mehrere Knoten verbunden sind, oder eine Baum- oder Rhizomstruktur. Stingenz ist quasi der simpelste Fall von Kohärenz.

Comment: Ok, danke für die Antwort, das hilft mir weiter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Etwas ist kohärent, wenn es zusammenhängend ist (Lateinisch *cohaerēre*: *co* = zusammen/miteinander und *haerēre* = hängen/kleben/haften).

Kohärente Lehrinhalte sind also Lehrinhalte, die zusammengehören.

Mit »roter Faden« sagt man aber aus, dass es eine sinnvolle Reihenfolge der Lehrinhalte gibt, dass also das Eine auf nachvollziehbare Weise zum Nächsten führt. Das ist eine Erweiterung der Bedeutung von *kohärent*, die in *kohärent* selbst nicht enthalten ist.

Wenn man sagt, dass ein Text kohärent ist, meint man, dass es darin um Themen geht, die miteinander zu tun haben. Man meint damit nicht unbedingt, dass der Text eine klare Linie (also einen *roten Faden*) hat. Das sind zwar ähnliche Dinge, aber nicht sie sind nicht genau gleich.

Comment: Danke für die Differenzierung, das hatte ich so nicht gesehen.

Comment: Eine kohärente Auffassung, stringent präsentiert!